# Count or select in Excel from 1 column based on another column

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I've got following example in Excel

[image]

I want to know or indicate in an extra Excel column, if there are different TypeEvents in a period block.
For period 1 there is only 1 type event -> so no different TypeEvents
For period 4 there are 2 type events but they are the same -> so no different TypeEvents
For period 8 there are 2 type events and they are not the same -> this one is different and count as one.

It's also possible that for example for period 20 there are 6 type events (3times WNS and 3 times WGV) -> this one is different and count as one! Not as many but as one.

Is this possible with a pivot or with a sql statement on the table or with some VBA script or ...?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `COUNTIFS`

The formula that I am using is based on the data starting (headers) in cell`a1`. I put the following into cell `c2`. `COUNTIFS` is a dynamic array function so will autofill down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A13,A2:A13,B2:B13,"<>"&B2:B13)<>0,"Multi", "")
```

The first `countif` criteria selects rows with the same period and the second identifies a row with a different type event

[image]